# How do I compare a CombinedResponse object value with an int?

Tags: django

I'm trying to annotate a query with a percentage that repsents how "complete" the business logic is. I don't want that percentage to go over 100%. I currently have this in my query:

```
.annotate(completion=max(100, Count('id')/F('something_tricky') )
```

The issue is that `Count/F` is a `CombinedExpression`, which is unorderable, so can't be used in `max`. It won't let me cast it to an `int` either:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'CombinedExpression'

Or to a String.

How do I get the `completion` value as an int out of this query?

Comment: Have you tried `output_field`?

Comment: Sorry I mean `convert_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use database functions for annotations, in your case is [Greatest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) function.

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

.annotate(completion=Greatest(Value(100), Count('id')/F('something_tricky') )
```